# AWS Lambda function that has been working for weeks, one day timed out for no apparent reason. Ideas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I wrote a simple lambda function (in python 3.7) that runs once a day, which keeps my Glue data catalog updated when new partitions are created. It works like this:

- Object creation in a specific S3 location triggers the function asynchronously
- From the event, lambda extracts the key (e.g.: s3://my-bucket/path/to/object/)
- Through AWS SDK, lambda asks glue if the partition already exists
- If not, creates the new partition. If yes, terminates the process.

Also, the function has 3 print statements:

- one at the very beginning, saying it started  the execution
- one in the middle, which says if the partition exists or not
- one at the end, upon successful execution.

This function has an average execution time of 460ms per invocation, with 128MB RAM allocated, and it cannot have more than about 12 concurrent executions (as 12 is the maximum amount of new partitions that can be generated daily). There are no other lambda functions running at the same time that may steal concurrency capacity. Also, just to be sure, I have set the timeout limit to be 10 seconds.

It has been working flawlessly for weeks, except this morning, 2 of the executions timed out after reaching the 10 seconds limit, which is very odd given it's 20 times larger than the avg. duration.

What surprises me the most, is that in one case only the 1st print statement got logged in CloudWatch, and in the other case, not even that one, as if the function got called but never actually started the process.

I could not figure out what may have caused this. Any idea or suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

May be AWS had a problem with their services, I got the same issue.

Not sure it can help. You can check at:

https://status.aws.amazon.com

```
[CloudFront High Error Rate]
```

> 4:28 PM PDT We are investigating elevated error rates and elevated
>   latency in multiple edge locations. 5:08 PM PDT We can confirm
>   elevated error rates and high latency accessing content from multiple
>   Edge Locations, which is also contributing to longer than usual
>   propagation times for changes to CloudFront configurations. We have
>   identified the root cause and continue to work toward resolution. 5:54
>   PM PDT We are beginning to see recovery for the elevated error rates
>   and high latency accessing content from multiple Edge Locations. Error
>   rates have recovered for all locations except for Europe.
>   Additionally, we continue to work toward recovery for the increased
>   delays in propagating configuration changes to Cloudfront
>   Distributions. 6:21 PM PDT Starting 3:18 PM PDT, we experienced
>   elevated error rates and high latency accessing content from multiple
>   Edge Locations. The elevated error rates and elevated latency
>   accessing content were fully recovered at 5:48 PM PDT. During this
>   time, customers may also have experienced longer than usual change
>   propagation delays for CloudFront configurations and invalidations.
>   The backlog of CloudFront configuration changes and invalidations were
>   fully processed by 6:14 PM PDT. All issues have been fully resolved
>   and the system is operating normally

Comment: I understand, maybe I trust AWS a little too much with its fault tolerance. Admittedly, the time of when my lambda timed out was about 6 hours after (6:00 AM UTC) the feed said everything was fixed. Who knows.